# while installing request module i am getting an error

Tags: node.js

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of input at 1:155018
>
> npm ERR! .9.7","require-globify":"^1.3.0","typescript":"^2.0.3","uglify-js":"^
>   npm ERR!                                                                      ^
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-24T06_55_20_3
>   51Z-debug.log

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this command, as in my case this solved the problem:

```
npm cache clean --force
```